# Save datagridview into database - error occcured

Tags: c#, winforms, dataview

I try to save the datagridview data into the database. But I don't know how to store it. I try some methods but it return error. So please I need to know how to rectify this error and my code is

```
string Stu_rollno = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1];
string sub_code = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2];
```

My error is;

> Cannot implicity convert type 'system.windows.Forms.Datagridviewcell'
>   to 'string'

Please give solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

[`Cells` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.cells%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns [`DataGridViewCellCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and `Cells[1]` and `Cells[2]` returns [`DataGridViewCell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and there is no implicit conversation between `DataGridViewCell` and `string`.

You can use [`Value` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get associated cell value like;

```
string Stu_rollno = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
string sub_code = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 "INSERT INTO Nominal VALUES ('" + comboBox1.Text + "','" + comboBox2.Text + "','"
                                + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Stu_rollno"].Value + "',' "
                                + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Sub_code"].Value + "','"
                                + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Course_name"].Value + "');";
```

I use this for storing gridview data into the database

Comment: I don't think that's the case here.